# How do I get object if class is instantiated only like this new classname()

Tags: php

I want to get an object of a class, but class is instantiated only like this.

`new classname();`

Comment: And the problem is? `$foo = new classname();` - tada, `$foo` now is an object of that class. If you elaborate why you need that object, what you want to do with it, I might be able to give a proper answer

Comment: I could not do change in code of that already instantiated class.